# ODBC Teradata connection Julia

Tags: odbc, julia

I am trying to connect to Teradata using ODBC in Julia using the following but I am getting an error:

```
co = ODBC.connect(dsn = "DBS", uid = "me", pwd = "xxx")
```

Error:

```
>ArgumentError: function connect does not accept
```

I've installed the ODBC package and if I run `ODBC.listdsns()` I can see a list of available DSNs, one of which I am using in my connection string.  I've tried a few other variants that are listed in the documentation but I get the same error message.

I have been using the above connection string in R so I'm confident that I can connect with ODBC but I only installed Julia over the weekend so I am still getting to grips with it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The error message appears truncated. It that all the error that you see?